# Bootstrap2 input-small does not work on handphone

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, less, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have this code and I'm using `input-small` to make my textbox width shorter. It works on desktop and tablet but not on mobile.

```
<div class="input-append date">
    <input id="month" type="text" placeholder="Select Month" class="input-small"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
 </div>
```

On Desktop & tablet

[image]

Didn't worked on handphone though:

[image]

Any idea on how I can solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sudheer `input-small` does exist, but only in Bootstrap v2, which the OP is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your bootstrap-responsive.css, there is more specific css over riding that:

```
  .input-prepend input,
  .input-append input,
  .input-prepend input[class*="span"],
  .input-append input[class*="span"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
  }
```

To change **all** `.input-append` to use that `.input-small` width, do this **after** all other css:

```
@media (max-width:767px) {

   .input-append .input-small {width:90px;}

}
```

**OR be more specific if you only want to deal with that `.input-append`.**

```
@media (max-width:767px) {

   .small-input-append.input-append .input-small {width:90px;}

}
```

**Change your html to:**

```
<div class="small-input-append input-append date">
    <input id="month" type="text" placeholder="Select Month" class="input-small"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
 </div>
```